# Having difficulty with nested lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying a challenge but I can't seem to figure out how to access the lists under "important classes" in the dictionary. If I try

```
class_sched = [x for y in innerList['important classes'] for x in y]
```

I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str:`

```
tester = {
  "info": [
    {
      "name": "Lauren",
      "class standing": "Junior",
      "major": "Information Science",
      "important classes": ["SI 106", "ENGLISH 125", "SI 110", "AMCULT 202"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Ayo",
      "class standing": "Bachelor's",
      "major": "Information Science",
      "important classes": [ "SI 106", "SI 410", "PSYCH 111"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Adam",
      "major": "Violin Performance",
      "class standing": "Senior",
      "important classes": ["PIANO 101", "STUDIO 300", "THEORY 229", "MUSC 356"]
    }
  ]
}

innerList = tester['info']

class_sched = [x for y in innerList for x in y]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why you expect `innerList['important classes']` to work when you've named `innerList` indicating that you know it is a list. Since this is a list containing multiple dictionaries, each with its own `'important classes'` key, it is not clear what your desired output is; do you want the first one? Both together in a single list? A list of lists? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: You only have one list to iterate over: `[x for x in innerList['important classes']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a nested list like this:

```py
tester = {
    "info": [
        {
            "name": "Lauren",
            "class standing": "Junior",
            "major": "Information Science",
            "important classes": ["SI 106", "ENGLISH 125", "SI 110", "AMCULT 202"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Ayo",
            "class standing": "Bachelor's",
            "major": "Information Science",
            "important classes": ["SI 106", "SI 410", "PSYCH 111"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "major": "Violin Performance",
            "class standing": "Senior",
            "important classes": ["PIANO 101", "STUDIO 300", "THEORY 229", "MUSC 356"]
        }
    ]
}

class_sched = [item for dictionary in tester['info'] for item in dictionary.get('important classes',[])]

print(class_sched)
```

**Output:**

```
['SI 106', 'ENGLISH 125', 'SI 110', 'AMCULT 202', 'SI 106', 'SI 410', 'PSYCH 111', 'PIANO 101', 'STUDIO 300', 'THEORY 229', 'MUSC 356']
```

Comment: Thanks, y'all! I think I understand now.